# My while loop in the rock, paper and scissor game isn't working. How should I correct it?

Tags: python

The game should end when either the human or the computer reaches 5 points. This game was just a function before. I then added the input function and the while loop to make it more efficient and user-friendly.

```
import random

choices=('rock','paper','scissor')
HUMAN_SCORE=0
COMPUTER_SCORE=0


while COMPUTER_SCORE<5 or HUMAN_SCORE<5:
    computer=random.choice(choices)
    human=input("Choose from rock,paper or scissor")
    print("You picked:")
    print(human)
    print("Computer picked:")
    print(computer)
    if human == "rock" and computer == "rock":
        print("play again")
    elif human == "rock" and computer == "paper":
        COMPUTER_SCORE=COMPUTER_SCORE+1
        print("sorry,you lost!Better luck next time!")
    elif human == "rock" and computer == "scissor":
        HUMAN_SCORE=HUMAN_SCORE+1
        print("Congratulations,you won!")
    elif human == "paper" and computer == "paper":
        print("play again")
    elif human == "paper" and computer == "scissor":
        COMPUTER_SCORE = COMPUTER_SCORE + 1
        print("sorry,you lost!Better luck next time!")
    elif human == "paper" and computer == "rock":
        print("Congratulations,you won!")
        HUMAN_SCORE = HUMAN_SCORE + 1
    elif human == "scissor" and computer == "scissor":
        print("play again")
    elif human == "scissor" and computer == "rock":
        print("sorry,you lost!Better luck next time!")
        COMPUTER_SCORE = COMPUTER_SCORE + 1
    elif human == "scissor" and computer == "paper":
        print("Congratulations,you won!")
        HUMAN_SCORE = HUMAN_SCORE + 1
    else:
        print("try again!Choose from the options above!")
    print("Human_Score=")
    print(HUMAN_SCORE)
    print("Computer_Score=")
   `print(COMPUTER_SCORE)
```

Comment: Define "isn't working". Not looping at all? Looping a fewer number of times than you'd expect? Looping a larger number of times than you'd expect? Looping forever? Something else?

Comment: Hint: consider that `COMPUTER_SCORE<5 or HUMAN_SCORE<5:` evaluates to True when `COMPUTER_SCORE` equals 4, and `HUMAN_SCORE` equals ten million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while COMPUTER_SCORE<5 or HUMAN_SCORE<5:
```

Most likely this will always be true (the human or computer can't both hit 5 at the same time so one must be true)

You need to make sure they're both less than 5 with `and`

```
while COMPUTER_SCORE<5 and HUMAN_SCORE<5:
```